# canvas tile .png loses opacity during animation

Tags: jquery, html, canvas, png, opacity

I'm a novice when it comes to Canvas. I don't, however, have a choice not to use it.

http://cl.ly/3T1M0n3x431V3H330T1G

The bottom bit of the shape animates out upon clicking 'disclaimer'. It is in a different canvas than the top bit with the faint lines. The lines in both cases are created by tiling a png with alpha.

Why does the opacity change during animation, but only sometimes?

Here is the bit that animates:

```
var menu_canvas = {
animator: function(y, targetY, state){

    var canvas = document.getElementById('menu_animator'),
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
        dy,
        easing =0.5,
        canvas_loop = '';
        state   = (y < targetY) ? 'closed' : 'opened';

    canvas_loop = setInterval(draw,10);

    function draw(){

        // update position
        dy=targetY-y;       //Vertikale afstand
        y+=dy * easing;     // vy=vertikale snelheid

        // clear canvas
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        // draw                    
        var gradient;
        var imageObj = new Image();

            ctx.shadowColor = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75)";
            ctx.shadowOffsetX = 5.0;
            ctx.shadowOffsetY = 5.0;
            ctx.shadowBlur = 20.0;
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.lineTo(294, y-50);
            ctx.lineTo(294, y-22);
            // ... here rest of shape is drawn ...
            ctx.lineTo(25, y-22);
            ctx.lineTo(25, y-50);
            ctx.closePath();
            gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 77, 0, 175);
            gradient.addColorStop(0, "#e923ac");
            gradient.addColorStop(1, "#f7069e");
            ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
            ctx.fill();

            imageObj.onload = function(){
            var pattern = ctx.createPattern(imageObj, "repeat");

            ctx.fillStyle = pattern;
            ctx.fill();
        };
        imageObj.src = "cdn/gfx/bg_tile.png";

        if ((state == 'opened' && y < (targetY + 0.5)) || (state == 'closed' && y > (targetY - 0.5))) {
            clearInterval(canvas_loop)
        }

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this on more than one browser? I've never had an issue with opacity changing during animation

Comment: yes, the problem seems to be webkit specific